# How to identify a Message Box on my Desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I have just noticed a little pop up input box on my Desktop that has no Close, Minimise or Maximise buttons in the top right, I was wondering where has this guy come from? I was in Outlook 2013 with an popped out open message when I spotted him. Although it could have came from anywhere.

How can I find out where this came from?

I also cannot type anything into this box; it's just there.  I was also working on an Excel spread sheet at the time. (I realise that this may not give any indication its just all I can give at the moment).

Here is a picture of the sneaky message box:

[image: message box image]

Comment: Have you analyzed your running processes via task manager? Perhaps if you list all processes, you might be able to identify the application.

Comment: I could not find it in the processes but when I right clicked it, it gave me an option to Open IME this then allowed me to type in the box there's now a right click option to close IME

Comment: It Closed with Alt+F4 but now I do not know how to get it running again! haha

Comment: Does this box appear after a reboot? If you close the box using the option "close IME", does it reappear on it's own? Have you ran an antivirus scan? (Any findings?)

Comment: It's a hidden window that's unintentionally been made visible.  I've seen it several times over the years, and it's probably an Office-related process remnant (perhaps due to a plugin misbehaving, or while waiting for a process that took longer than expected).  Use Process Explorer or alike to figure out who owns it the next time it shows up (if it ever does again).

Comment: it wasn't anything malicious and no the close IME did not do anything I could still type in the box :s

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 would typing in that box effect any of my Office programs?

Comment: @NathanTaylor It never has for me, even when I was trying yo make it do bad things.  As far as I'm concerned from when I looked into it myself, it's purely an artifact from a process that ended unexpectedly.  But let's not do hypotheticals (SU doesn't like them) -- Are you running into an actual problem caused by the box? Can you reproduce it regularly? If the answer is "no" to either of those questions, then we can't help you at this point -- you need to do more investigation and provide those results to us.

Comment: no it wasn't harming my computer at all I was just wondering where it came from now that I know it was to do with Office its pretty much answered so if you want to answer it i'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), you can find out which program opened that window or message box.

[image: process explorer window tool]

From the interface, drag and drop the icon from the toolbar that looks like a cross in a circle.  Drag it from the toolbar and drop it on the mystery window.

Then in the Process Explorer window, the highlighted process (in blue) will be the program that is responsible for that window.

Comment: Ah that is a really handy tool I will remember that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this also, it appears to be related to acrobat reader. If I look at the Processes tab in task manager I had opened several web pages that are opening pdf files and had the process AcroRd32.exe running. When I killed this process, the window went away...

I think these came from an email that had links to pdf's, as I had several opened...  they don't appear unless I lock my screen and re-login. Kinda weird.

Comment: Try to answer more recents posts. You'll most likely get more reputation faster if you answer bounties or offer your advice to unanswered questions! Welcome to SuperUser, by the way!